# What are the different versions of Fruits Candy?

Tags: theme-song, cardcaptor-sakura

The 3rd ED to Cardcaptor Sakura is "Fruits Candy". There seem to be multiple versions of the song, but [MAL](http://myanimelist.net/anime/232/Cardcaptor_Sakura) only lists the one sung by Megumi Kojima. However, I've heard at least one other version (see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uNALWuWJao), and it wouldn't surprise me if there were more. Can anyone confirm what other versions of this song exist and who sings each of them?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you only asking for versions that were used in the show?

Comment: @atlantiza Ideally a perfect answer would have all of the instances in the CCS albums, but the ones used in the anime are the ones I'm most interested in.

Answer (score 1):

According to [wikia](http://ccs.wikia.com/wiki/Fruits_Candy), there is another version of the song sung by Sakura Tange, Junko Iwao and Aya Hisakawa, the voices of Sakura Kinomoto, Tomoyo Daidouji and Cerberus, respectively. So there are two versions in total.